# Connected IBOutlet component null?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have following code with following xib:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellLoadMore;
```

[image]

When I try to NSLog the cellLoadMore, it returns null, however, when I try to NSLog the view, it has value. What could be the problem of cellLoadMore returns null?

Below is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSLog(@"cell load more %@", cellLoadMore_);
  NSLog(@"view %@", self.view);
}
```

Console prints:

```
cell load more (null)
view <UITableView: 0x1284200; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa393b0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

**Note: My class is a subclass from UITableView.**

Comment: As I think borrrden is implying, the `view` of a view controller will load on demand but — generally speaking — other outlets will be connected only when the view is loaded. So if you were to log before the view is otherwise loaded then the behaviour you describe could be correct.

Comment: I NSlog it in viewDidLoad and I think the custom cell must be also have been loaded there? Because I have another class subclassed from UIViewController has custom cell and doesn't return nil when I NSLog in viewDidLoad

Comment: btw, pls see my edited post :)

Comment: you would have to log in viewDidLoad of the cell to be sure it has been loaded. Otherwise it doesn't have to be loaded in the viewDidLoad of the parent view. But this is only speculation. Post some code, then we can tell better.

Comment: why do you log it? doesn't your table loading properly?

Comment: because I want to load the custom cell somewhere in my tableview, but when I try it, it didn't show up because of null

Comment: I still can't have any solution for this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem some times and managed to solve it by change my controller from subclass of UITableViewController into UIViewController that using UITableview delegate.
This is quite annoying though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what is happening.  You are making a property, and an instance variable, but you are not synthesizing the property correctly.  By default on Xcode 4.4+ the property will be synthesized to `_cellLoadMore` and not `cellLoadMore_`.  On older versions, if you use simply `@synthesize cellLoadMore` then the variable will be `cellLoadMore`.  So basically, if you don't have a line that says `@synthesize cellLoadMore = cellLoadMore_`, then you have two different variables.

Comment: thanks borrrden, i will try it again at home later..thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably "logging" before the cell is loaded. The cell will be loaded the first time it is *really* used (google for "lazy loading"). If you access the view of the cell, it is *really* used and therefore really loaded. You can log the view and the cell after that and it shouldn't be null anymore.

Comment: Please see my comment above :)

Comment: Did you try?   NSLog(@"cell load more %@", self.cellLoadMore);